# how to set a dynamic error message in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling

Hello I'm trying to create a stored procedure to insert data int to the DB, but first I validate some of the parameters

if one or more of the validation is not met I want to raise an Exception and stop the stored procedure.

So far I can do this by exiting the execution as soon as the firs error is detected doing this:

```
    -- si existe el correo
            if exists(select 1 from tbl_users u where u.`e-mail` = p_email limit 1) then
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
               SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='Error: el correo ingreasdo ya existe';
            end if;
            -- convinacion de nombre y apellido ya existen
            IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_users u WHERE u.`Nombre` = p_Nombre and u.`Apellido`=p_Apellido limit 1  ) THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
               SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='El nombre y apellido ya fueron ingreasados anteriormente';
            END IF;
            -- si el pasword es valido y el tipo (p_fk_user_type_id) es:1 (supervisor)
            IF (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(p_Password)<4) and (p_fk_user_type_id <>1 ) THEN
               SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
               SET MESSAGE_TEXT ='El pasword es muy corto, debe tener al menos 4 caracteres';
            END IF;
```

What I need to do is to get all the errors and return them in a single error message
something like this:

```
 DECLARE mensaje VARCHAR(100);
        SET mensaje = '';
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_users u WHERE u.`e-mail` = p_email LIMIT 1) THEN
           SET mensaje = 'el correo ingreasdo ya existe');
        END IF;
        -- convinacion de nombre y apellido ya existen
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_users u WHERE u.`Nombre` = p_Nombre AND u.`Apellido`=p_Apellido LIMIT 1  ) THEN
           SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje,' ','El nombre y apellido ya fueron ingreasados anteriormente');
        END IF;
        -- si el pasword es valido y el tipo (p_fk_user_type_id) es:1 (supervisor)
        IF (SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(p_Password)<4) AND (p_fk_user_type_id <>1 ) THEN
           SET mensaje = CONCAT(mensaje, ' ' ,'El pasword es muy corto, debe tener al menos 4 caracteres');
        END IF;

        IF (mensaje <>"")THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = mensaje;
         ELSEIF 
           -- insert to database
        END IF;
```

Comment: What is the issue? What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `SET @mensaje = CONCAT(....)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41912414/509565).

The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html) (and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)) suggest that `mensaje` will be treated as a parameter passed to your procedure and `@mensaje` is the proper way to DECLARE a user variable.