# Formatting error message in MySQL error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out how to throw an error with formatted error message in MySQL (5.7).

```
// SOME PROCEDURE
begin
declare something INT;
start transaction;
    call getsomething(something); // sets something to data
    if something is NULL then
        rollback;
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Something %d not found!', MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
    end if;
commit;
end
```

How can I use "something" variable when creating error message?

Comment: Mybe that help https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Answer (score 2):

```
// SOME PROCEDURE
begin
declare something INT;
declare error_msg VARCHAR(255);
start transaction;
    call getsomething(something); // sets something to data
    if something is NULL then
        rollback;
        set error_msg = CONCAT('Something not found!', something);
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = error_msg, MYSQL_ERRNO = 1001;
    end if;
commit;
end
```

Following @Samis comment and retrying using CONCAT - above works.

Answer (score 1):

What about `CONCAT()` and local variable to store the message?

```
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = CONCAT(something, 'not found!');
```

[working example](https://gist.github.com/doobry/1106727)